# knockout push not updating GUI

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I am struggeling with knockout and getting the UI too update when i add an item to an observableArray. The intial listing and deleteEmployee are working fine and update the UI appropriatley but when i try to add an employee the the UI is simply not updated. Below is the viewmodel and the html. Appreciate any help i can get on this. 
    
    
**ViewModel:**

```
function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.employees = ko.observableArray();

        self.deleteEmployee = function () {
            var employee = this;
            dataservice.del(this.id, function () {
                self.employees.remove(employee);
            })
        },

        self.addEmployee = function () {
            var emp = {};
            emp.Name = $("#newName").val();
            emp.Email = $("#newEmail").val();
            dataservice.add(emp, function (data) {
                var employee = new Employee(data.id, emp.Name, emp.Email);
                self.employees.push(employee);
            });
        }.bind(self);

        $.each(data.rows, function (index, row) {
            self.employees.push(new Employee(row.value.Id, row.value.Name, row.value.Email));
        });

        return {
            employees: self.employees,
            deleteEmployee: self.deleteEmployee,
            addEmployee: self.addEmployee
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**Html**

```
<article data-bind="foreach: employees">
                <div class="emp">
                    <div class="empTop">
                        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                        <div class="del" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteEmployee, clickBubble: false"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="empContent">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" data-bind="value: name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="name">Email</label>
                            <input name="email" type="text" data-bind="value: email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="button" value="Update">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                 
            </article>

            <aside>
                <h3>Create</h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="newName">Name</label>
                        <input id="newName" name="newName" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="newEmail">Email</label>
                        <input id="newEmail" name="newEmail" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="button" value="Create" data-bind="click: addEmployee">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
```

Comment: btw. I am getting no errors or anything like that. the only problem i am having is that the UI is not updated. if i refresh the page after i add an employee it appears there correctly in the list

Comment: It seems to me that dataservice.add doesn't call callback function. Did you try to debug it? Is self.employees.push(employee); function called?

Comment: yes the self.employees.push(employee); is called and the employee object cointains the correct data.

Comment: The strange thing is that the initial $.each() with push() populates everything correctly and the page is rendered with all my employees listed. remove also woks fine and updates the ui but then the addEmployee does nothing when push() is called. i am confused :S.

Comment: Try to add a fake Employee in addEmployee function:         self.addEmployee = function () {
                self.employees.push(new Employee(1, "Test", "Test");
        }. And test if it works.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code but without using dataservice and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/UQrpp/

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the problem is not with the Knockout. I put your code into JSFiddle, commented out several lines in javascript, but hadn't touch your HTML, and creating is working fine.

Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mshmelev/ZF5pC/

So, the problem could be:

1. `dataservice.add()` function is not calling your callback
2. Something is wrong with your `Employee` class (I created just a stub in the fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the items where getting rendered but, this is embarrasing, i had some jquery that was hiding the elements beeing added $('.emp').hide(). This little mistake cost me severla hours of confusion. thankyou for all your suggestions.